# Is there a way to restore service fabric services and applications to a different cluster configuration than when it was backed up

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric

The use case is when a node is unavailable for one reason or another, and the active processes on the partition need to be moved to another node, and have this be the case during a restore as well.
From what I understand, the manual restore process has you restore each partition individually. I have created a test where I removed a node from the cluster, and initiated a restore from an automated backup.

Is there a way to change the name of the node that a partition is on?
Additionally, given the application definition exists on the cluster and the cluster can support that service configuration, is there a way to restore to a different cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a backup works on the level of a partition. The name of the node that runs the primary service replica for that partition is not important.

The amount of partitions on source and target needs to be equal.

More info:
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-backup-restore-service-trigger-restore#data-restore-in-the-case-of-disaster-recovery),
[here](https://github.com/microsoft/Service-Fabric-AppDRTool), and
[here](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/322)